# Frequency Analysis program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties

i'm new in python programming. and now in part of program, i want to define a class for Frequency Analysis and print it in pretty style:

```
Letter    Occurrence    Percentage
  a          12            4.12%
  b          7             3.15%
  c          21            7.67%
 ...        ...             ...
```

here is my code:

```
class Analysis():

    def __init__(self, sentence, freq_dict = {}):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.freq_dict = freq_dict

    @property
    def frequency(self):
        print("\t\tLetter\t\tOccurrence\t\tPrecentage")
        for letter, occurrence in enumerate(self.freq_dict):
            return f"\t\t{letter}\t\t{occurrence}\t\t{round(occurrence*100/len(sentence), 2)}%"

    @frequency.setter
    def frequency(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence
        for letter in sentence:
            freq_dict[letter] = self.sentence.count(letter)
        return freq_dict


sentence = input("please enter your sentence: ").lower()
object = Analysis(sentence)
print(object.frequency())
```

i want to define the input the sentence inside the class, not as global variable.

maybe it can be shorter or change some lines. (instead of a dictionary, maybe i can use the collections.Counter(sentence), it return a tuple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few wrongs in your code.
here is a couple of changes that you can to do.

1- to define an input function inside the class(not as a global variable), you can define a classmethod named get_sentence

2- you can use Counter() from collections module to made a dictionary of letters and their occurrences.
to extract and print the result, you can define `extract()` instance method.

(it will be sort the result by the highest occurrence to the lowest.)

**the code will be like this:**

```
from collections import Counter

class Analysis():

    def __init__(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence

    def extract(self):
        print("\n\t\tLetter\t\tOccurrence\t\tPrecentage")
        print(f"\t\t {'-' * 39}")
        sorted_f = sorted(Counter(self.sentence).items(), key = lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
        for letter, occurrence in sorted_f:
            print(f"\t\t  {letter}\t\t\t    {occurrence}\t\t\t  {round(occurrence * 100 / len(self.sentence), 2)}%")
        return " "

    @classmethod
    def get_sentence(cls):
        sentence = input("Enter your sentence: ").lower().replace(" ", "")
        return cls(sentence)

obj = Analysis.get_sentence()
obj.extract()
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ```
>       Letter      Occurrence      Precentage
>       ---------------------------------------
>         e             5             21.74%
>         n             4             17.39%
>         s             3             13.04%
>         t             3             13.04%
>         i             2             8.7%
>         o             1             4.35%
>         m             1             4.35%
>         c             1             4.35%
>         h             1             4.35%
>         p             1             4.35%
>         u             1             4.35%
> ```